# JanusGraph Java Serializer for propertyMap()

Tags: java, serialization, graph-databases, tinkerpop, janusgraph

Im setting up a simple Java application that runs some queries on top of a given Graph Database (either Neo4j or JanusGraph).

I would like to have interface methods with return type and general form as this:
`Collection<Map<String, Object>> findPersonByName(String name)`

For Neo4j, the spring-client by default fetches records in the form of `Map<String, Object>` e.g **{"name", "mario"}**, so no problem.

For JanusGraph/Tinkerpop based dbs, the traversal propertyMap() does the same, but the resulting values of the pairs have annoying surrounding tokens e.g **{"name", "vp[name->mario]"}**

Is there a serializer suited for my purposes?
Follows the driver connection and dependencies in use:

```
            TypeSerializerRegistry typeSerializerRegistry = TypeSerializerRegistry.build()
                    .addRegistry(JanusGraphIoRegistry.instance())
                    .create();

            Cluster cluster = Cluster.build(host)
                    .port(Integer.parseInt(port))
                    .serializer(new GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1(typeSerializerRegistry))
                    .enableSsl(false)
                    .create();
            Object driver = traversal().withRemote(
                    DriverRemoteConnection.using(cluster, "g")
            );
```

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
        <artifactId>janusgraph-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
        <artifactId>gremlin-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

I've tried other serializers as GraphSON, but all of them fail when it comes to use the propertyMap() method in a graph traversal as the following

`g.V().hasLabel("Person").propertyMap().by(unfold()).toList()`

Comment: Ended up giving up on the desired interface method return type 
`Collection<Map<String, Object>> findPersonByName(String name)` and switching to a Node domain class return type with converter method
`g.V().hasLabel("Person").elementMap().toStream().map(Node::fromGremlin).toList()`